# Facebook Open Graph Scraping URL

Tags: facebook, url, redirect, facebook-opengraph, scraper

I'm trying to develop 'want' and 'own' buttons.

If I use the [Facebook debug tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) it tells me the final URL is the home page and this has happened because the page has been redirected, which I don't want. I want the fetched URL to be scraped.

As a result of the Final URL **NOT** being the item page, the information scraped is incorrect and the debugging tool complains about a lack of meta data etc. I believe the correct information is on the item page but due to the redirect, incorrect information is parsed.

My questions are:

1) Why is this happening? - *Answer: A trailing slash broke our ISAPI rules*

2) How do I fix it? - *Answer: Remove the trailing slash or update ISAPI rules*

3) Can I force the scraper to use a specific URL and ignore any redirects? I'm using asp.net so any examples would be greatly appreciated.

The correct page was being scraped before however now it doesn't and I really don't know what has changed this....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Debug tool, you have a 302 redirect on the page when Facebook attempts to scrape your page.

`URLS REMOVED`

You need to find out why this is happening and disable it. It's causing Facebook to scrape the wrong URL as a result. Once fixed, your page should be scraped correctly.

Comment: Trying to do further tests using the exact same file but on different domains I get different results. Could this be as a result of the App settings on the Facebook dashboard?

Comment: Fixed. A trailing '/' was causing ISAPI to freak out.

Comment: FB keeps crawling to the next `og:url` every time it finds one. that is an issue sometimes